# Is there a way to bind a DataTable to an actual Table in a data base?

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable

Is there any way to bind a DataTable object to an actual table in my database? Right now I perform a query and fill the DataTable with the result. It would be really cool if I could just DataTable.(Save/Update) with out having to write additional code!

Is such a thing or a similar solution possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [DataAdapter.Update()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update(VS.71).aspx). You should write some code..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx) (template based code generator) and [EasyObjects](http://www.easyobjects.net/) (ORM Mapping library) which, when combined, get you pretty close to this. MyGeneration will even write the CRUD stored procedures for you (but you need to apply them to the db).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Entity Framework. With EF you make your changes and then call "savechanges", that will then persist any changes.